# Reduce the samples when rendering

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

Is there a way to speed up rendering times by reducing the number of samples, like the "4096" here:

```
Fra:86 Mem:1257.09M (Peak 2336.27M) | Time:00:04.50 | Remaining:35:15.04 | Mem:1289.36M, Peak:1289.36M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 1/4096
```

and does it make sense - at the risk of reducing quality a bit?

And - most important - is it possible to do it via python (version > 2.90)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual way to do this is via the properties editor.  The settings are in the *Render Properties* tab.  (See image)  For EEVEE they are the same in 2.9x and 3.x:

[image: EEVEE render settings highlighting samples]

and the Python code for changing them is

```py
SCENE.eevee.taa_render_samples = VALUE
```

replacing SCENE with the scene you want to change them for like `bpy.context.scene` and VALUE with the integer value you want.

For Cycles, there are two versions.  Cycles in 2.9x is "old Cycles".  Cycles in 3.x is "Cycles X".  Here are what the manual settings look like:

Old Cycles:

[image: old Cycles render settings]

and the python is

```py
SCENE.cycles.samples = Value
```

Cycles X:

[image: Cycles X Render Settings]

Cycles X has the same setting; but you might not want to use max samples.  See [Sampling](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html) in the Blender manual for details